# pdfpages error: ! Package keyval Error: page undefined

Tags: pdftex, pdf, pdfpages

This very simple working example does not work to include pdf and produces the error message "! Package keyval Error: page undefined.":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

Test

\includepdf[scale=0.7]{./a.pdf}

\end{document}
```

From `log`-file:

> ```
> (/home/wyousef/texmf/tex/latex/Bioinformatics/graphicx.sty
> Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
>
> (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
> Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
>
> (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
> Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
> )
> (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
> File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
> )
> Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.
> )
> \Gin@req@height=\dimen105
> \Gin@req@width=\dimen106
> )
> ```
>
> …
>
> ```
> ./tmp.tex:9: Package keyval Error: page undefined.
>
> See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.9 \includepdf[pages=-]{./a.pdf}
> ```

Comment: Show your log-file. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: I have done archlinux update for everything using
sudo packman -Suy

Comment: This doesn't mean that you have an up-to-date tex. So show the log-file.

Comment: This is not accessible.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1iCA_eP9jXBYXhfOV80bEtXNEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The `log` file does not match the example above (`\includepdf[scale=0.7]{./a.pdf}` vs. `\includepdf[pages=-]{./a.pdf}`) ! Nevertheless, you have a very outdated `/home/wyousef/texmf/tex/latex/Bioinformatics/graphicx.sty` from 1999, that is found before the `graphicx.sty` of the distribution. You should remove at least this outdated file or maybe rename the whole `/home/wyousef/texmf` into `/home/wyousef/texmf.outdated`.

Comment: Ok, this is a new log file after I deleted everything and compiled anew:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1iCA_eP9jXBVnBHWF9nSUtZWG8/view?usp=sharing

BTW, why sudo packman -Syu does not update my LaTeX system? What should I do to update everything?

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thanks a million; it is indeed the old style file. But I then have the following important question:
1- why LaTeX used it and did not use the one that comes with the distribution?
2- How I update all my LaTeX system (as I posted in the above comment)?

Comment: local files wins over default files.  Your system is quite up-to-date.

Answer (score 6):

The `log` file does not match the example above (`\includepdf[scale=0.7]{./a.pdf}` in the example but `\includepdf[pages=-]{./a.pdf}` in the `log`-file)!

Nevertheless, the `log`-file shows, that you have a very outdated `/home/wyousef/texmf/tex/latex/Bioinformatics/graphicx.sty` from 1999, that is found before the `graphicx.sty` of the distribution, because it is in your `TEXMFHOME` tree which is usually searched before, e.g., the distribution tree `TEXMFDIST` or `TEXMFMAIN`, which is `/usr/share/texmf-dist/` in your case.

You should remove at least this outdated file `/home/wyousef/texmf/tex/latex/Bioinformatics/graphicx.sty` so that TeX Live (namely `kpsewhich`) will find `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty`. All other files seem to be up-to-date, so that I'd expect the distribution `graphicx.sty` also to be up-to-date.

Instead of removing only this old file, you could also suggest to rename `/home/wyousef/texmf`, e.g., into `/home/wyousef/texmf.outdated`. In this case `kpsewhich` and other TeX applications should not longer find files in this TEXMF-tree. If you later find, that you need files from there, you could copy only those files to the correct destination in a new `/home/wyousef/texmf`.

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks for the solution.